# Filtering a query by another query while allowing record input

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 queries. A, B.

Query A has several columns of data and B has only 1 column. When I link A & B I get exactly what I want (filtered records of A).

However, I still do want to input new data into the query, how do I do this?

Comment: We need the SQL of your queries and some sample data to help you. --- Maybe you are looking for http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html or http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

Comment: http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html is exactly what I have been looking for. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then :)
Question was how to make a query with JOINs updateable.

See: [Dealing with Non-Updateable Microsoft Access Queries and the Use of Temporary Tables](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html)

> **Reasons why a Query or Recordset is not Updateable**
>
> There are many reasons why your data may not be updateable. Some are
>   pretty obvious:
>
> - The query is a Totals query (uses GROUP BY) or Crosstab query (uses TRANSFORM), so the records aren't individual records
> - The field is a calculated field, so it can't be edited
> - You don't have permissions/rights to edit the table or database
> - The query uses VBA functions or user defined functions and the database isn't enabled (trusted) to allow code to run
>
> Some reasons are less obvious but can't be avoided:
>
> - Linked tables without a primary key for certain backend databases (e.g. SQL Server). Access/Jet requires the table to be keyed to make
>     any changes. This makes sense since Access wants to issue a SQL query
>     for modifications but can't uniquely identify the record.
>
> Less obvious are these situations:
>
> - Queries with some fields are summaries linked to individual records and the individual records still can't be edited
> - Queries with multi-table joins that aren't on key fields
> - Union queries

Another resource: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html